# Apache directory with a new install shows 404

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, wiki

I just went through all the steps to configure something to be run on Apache called OntoWiki.  I set up and tested Apache, PHP, and other tools that are required and all seem to be fine.

If I go to http://localhost/ I do see my Apache server loading up.  But if I go to http://localhost/myow/ (the directory if the installation) then it gives me a 404 page.

I checked and I do have a directory /var/www/myow in my Ubuntu setup.  Any idea for what can be causing the 404 page to get displayed despite having the right directory?

I even changed the directory permissions to be 777, but the OntoWiki welcome page is still not getting served up.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Take a look at your error log in /var/log/apache2/error_log

If you are getting a 404 then the entry in the error log should show the full path that apache is trying to access.

Comment: Yup, already looking there, and it makes sense.  Or I can be blind which is not out of the question :)

Comment: And the exact error from the log is???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was this issue:
[Apache directories under /var/www](https://serverfault.com/questions/252864/apache-directories-under-var-www)