# Apache directories under /var/www

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, php

I inherited an Apache configuration with a piece I don't really understand.
The directory path there is

```
/var/www/somedir.dev/
```

And if you point the browser to

```
http://localhost/
```

it actually shows the index.php file from the somedir.dev directory and not the root directory. Why would it be?  Can there have been some config that had made the default be that /somedir.dev/ directory?  Nothing under the root resolves anymore.  How can I make things under root be recognized by the server again?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For an Ubuntu system, the usual place you want to look is the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` directory. The files in there will define how you vhosts are configured. In particular check the [DocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#documentroot) settings for you virtual hosts.

Answer (score 1):

What is your 'DocumentRoot' set to in your httpd.conf?

It may be set to: DocumentRoot "/var/www/somedir.dev"